Fly CLI does not update Concourse pipeline after indicating pipeline updated successfully
I have a Concourse pipeline that I need to update, so I log in using the Fly CLI and attempt to perform the update using 'set-pipeline'.  I receive no errors and get a message that the update happened, however the changes have not saved.
The command I am using is
fly set-pipeline -t my-target --pipeline my-pipeline --config pipeline.yml --load-vars-from config.yml 
After this command I am shown a diff with the old version and the changes I want to make (the only changes are actually to variables in the config.yml file, and they appear to have populated in the pipeline file as expected).  Then there are some deprecation warnings related to variables with uppercase names, then I am asked if I want to update.  I enter 'y' and am told configuration updated.  All indicators seem to point to it completing successfully, but running get-pipeline afterwards shows the old pipeline version without my changes.
I have verified that I am logged in, it appears I have adequate permissions (owner), and my version matches what is being run on the server.  Other members of my team are able to update this pipeline without issue, so it doesn't seem related to the deprecation warnings (we will eventually take care of these).  We have not been able to identify any difference between their systems and mine.
Any ideas of what would cause this or suggestions of what to check?
